# the height of shape lost via cycle!

Tags: cycles-render-engine

this is a frame of my render with eevee
[image]

and this is a frame of my render with cycle
[image]

why I lost the height in cycle?
I didn't change anything. just changed the render engine and rendered.what is wrong?

Comment: Hello :). Your ground probably has displacement, which only works in Cycles. Notice the shape keeps it's height, but the ground rises :).

Comment: thanks, Mr. Jachym Michal.